# In Windows XP Home Edition, I need to view ASP files in Abyss

Tags: asp-classic

The operating system I am using is XP Home Edition and I just need to be able to view ASP files within a browser so I can make simple edits.

I have installed Abyss onto the machine but I'm not entirely sure if this will support asp files or if I need to install something else to make them run. Or if I need to setup something in Abyss so I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Abyss is and never heard of it before.

Your best chance is to install IIS 7.5 Express that supports Windows XP SP3+ ([source](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-express-faq/))

[Download here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038)